# How to include my own Ruby (on rails) functions inside an HTML page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a web-app. 
While it works great, writing whole pieces of code inside "<% %>" tags in ruby on rails is pretty ugly.

I tried to define a function in my controller.rb and then call it from the html page.
This does not work, as it does not recognize the function.

I'd appreciate any help here. Did I put my function in the correct place? Do I need to load using "require"?

For example:

**controller file:**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
 end
 def myfunc(x)
  puts x
 end
end
```

**HTML file (index.html):**

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>
<%= myfunc(5) %>
</p>
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are referring to is called a helper in Rails. There are two ways that you could implement this.

Option number one is to place the method you want to access inside a helper module. The most common one is ApplicationHelper which you can find in `RAILS_ROOT/app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. If you place the method in there it will be accessible from the views.

Another way if you still want/need to have the method in the controller, then you can use the `helper_method` function like this:

```
def WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :my_func

private
  def my_func(x)
    puts x
  end
end
```

The usage of `private` is not needed, but only good practice so that the method cannot be accidentally used as a Controller action or something.

Comment: If it's not really related to presentation but more to do with the object - say you have a controllers/PatientController, models/Patient and views/Patient - then the function can go in the model/Patient. You can then call it within the controller by declaring a new instance of Patient.
Also (at least I used to use this approach in Rails 2) you can set up a class in the lib folder then use 'require' to pull it into the controller that you need to use it with - find this approach useful for generic classes such as storage objects, that I use all over the place.

Comment: I have a followup question. I tried the following:  
module WelcomeHelper
 class Fixnum
  def myfunc
   p self*2
  end
 end
 def whadup(x)
  x.myfunc
 end
end
and when I call <%= 3.whadup %> in the HTML it says:
NoMethodError in Welcome#index
Showing C:/Sites/ridemo/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:
undefined method `whadup' for 3:Fixnum

Why won't it recognize the function? It seems to work fine in the command line of irb.

Comment: That's not how helpers work. Helper methods are stand alone, not extensions of existing classes. If you want to add instance methods to an existing class then you should keep those files in RAILS_ROOT/lib for example but that is something completely different from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails has a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture - in those architectures you can't access the controller from the view.

You could set a variable with the output from your function, and access that variable from your view